# Troubleshooting water hammer issues in heating system with TRVs on radiators

Tags: heating, valve, radiator, troubleshooting, water-hammer

Sorry that my first post has to be a long one...

## Update: two radiators in bypass do not solve the issue

The water hammer noises have certainly decreased, but I've heard them again closing a hot water faucet with TWO radiators without TRV.

## The problem, and the story so far

After I bought my current house, I installed a modern condensation heating unit (Bosch Condens 7000iW 35 C 23) - which also does domestic hot water, and a tado° smart thermostat + tado° TRVs on every radiator in the house. The entire system was sold to me as a package by my energy utilities provider.

With all the TRVs mounted, when the heater is working I have experienced severe banging/rattling noise in proximity of one TRV on a radiator, which would appear frequently (several times a day) and last long (20+ seconds).

As suggested by the Bosch technical center (who is not the installer), I have unmounted one of the TRVs, so that one of the radiators acts as a bypass, and the problem was reduced, but not completely solved. Now, I would the same noise only occasionally, in various parts of the system (often, but seemingly not always, on a particular TRV), and the phenomenon could also be caused by closing a hot-water faucet of the **domestic water circuit** (after 10/15 seconds, I would then hear the noise).

<strike>Unmounting a second TRV seems to solve the issue.</strike> **Not anymore, please see update at the top.**

It seems to me that the phenomenon is that of water hammer. Ideally, for complete control and cost optimization I would like the system to operate with all TRVs mounted. I've tried solving the issues with professionals, but so far no luck:

1. I have tried going back to the installer of the heating unit. They mentioned that I would need a differential bypass valve, but then didn't follow up on an estimate request from me. Given that they are not close to where I live, I have asked my local plumber to intervene; they have installed the bypass valve, but took no responsibility from the start on it solving the issue. Needless to say, the issue was not solved.
2. I have now re-opened a ticket with my energy provider (which officially provided me the system, and is responsible for re-contacting the installer, who in turn will contact me); in the meanwhile, I ask here to be better prepared, because it seems to me that professionals are not scientifically troubleshooting the issue, and I'm not getting closer to a solution.

I have made a diagram of my home plant:

[image: heating plant diagram]

Notes:

- All components of floor -1 on the left are located in the same room, the pipes with the manifolds are located in the garage some meters away
- The lower manifold is located in the garage (floor -1) and serves the 4 radiators on the ground floor
- The second manifold is located on the first floor, and serves the 4 radiators on the same floor
- **The expansion tank listed in the diagram was removed by the installer of the new unit, because he said it wouldn't be necessary anymore**
- With only one TRV unmounted, the problem would not be present always, but only when the temperature of the noisy TRV would be close to the set one (and so I figured the TRV would be **partially open**).
- It would make no difference if the TRV was umounted on the ground or 1st floor, from a big or a smaller radiator

## My primary question

1. Based on the information I have provided, is there an accurate method for troubleshooting and solving the problem, while using all of the TRVs? Is my request reasonable, i.e. do I have grounds for keep insisting with the installer and Bosch center that the system should work as I want, with no convenient (for them) workarounds? I am not doing DIY here, so my goal is to understand how if the professionals I'm involving are saying things that make sense.

### Secondary, minor questions

2. Why is the bypass valve not working? It goes from 1 bar up to 5 bar, and even opening it all the way (1 bar) does not make water flow through the bypass (the pipe does not get hot). The heating unit is operating above 1 bar (from the analog hand reading).
3. Also, admitting that it was working (e.g. by using a different valve), is there a good chance that it wouldn't completely solve the problem? After all, with only one of the TRVs unmounted (and therefore a radiator acting as a bypass), the problem will not completely go away. (**and even with two apparently, please see update at the top)**
4. Could the additional expansion tank that was removed help mitigate the issue? The Bosch manual says that an additional expansion tank is not required at factory pressure (curve number II in the image), 60 °C if the volume of water is less than 200 l (my plumber says it certainly is). Could the problem indicate that the installer/technical center have to check for anomalies in the internal expansion tank?

If you read until here, thanks for your patience, and thanks in advance for your valuable help!

[image: expansion tank curves]

Comment: You've been around SE/SO long enough to know that it's one question per post. Please break this up. Also, presuming that "expansion vase" is just an unusual translation of "expansion tank", it seems that this _might_ well be the problem. AIUI, expansion tanks can go a long way toward arresting water hammer. There are also water hammer arrestors that are _specifically designed_ for just that purpose. Seems like it may well be a simple fix.

Comment: Thank you @FreeMan for your comment. I would prefer posting a short question, too bad here I feel that I would have to repeat the context every single time. The important question here is whether I'm going in the right direction with my requests towards professionals; I tried prioritizing the post. Also, I have replaced my erroneous translation, now it's "tank" everywhere.

Comment: @FreeMan I'm sure your "AIUI" has great value based on knowledge, but all information I've aquired through the Internet is a collection of "AIUI"s. I'm looking for suggestions on how to tackle the issue with method, and since I don't know much about plumbing, sure, the expansion tank sounds reasonable from what I've read, but so did the installer who said "let's remove it because the unit already has one", and my plumber who says "let's not remount it because it would not help". I'm looking for ways to make up my mind and have solid grounds to contest erroneous decisions or explanations.

Comment: @0x5C91, can you indicate what form of domestic hot water system you have? Is it a large storage tank, a small (1 - 2 l) storage tank, a flow-through/combi boiler?

Comment: @BartvanIngenSchenau it is the very same boiler listed in the question, which does both radiator heating and domestic hot water (sorry if that wasn't clear from the question, edited to specify). I have no external storage tank, and I'm not an expert but from the manual I don't see indications of the device internally storing hot water (I think it produces it on-demand).

Comment: @0x5C91, I understood it was the same appliance, but there are multiple ways to produce domestic hot water, even if you use the same appliance for both hot water and central heating. It seems like you have a combi appliance (flow-through or on-demand are other terms used to refer to such an appliance).

Comment: @BartvanIngenSchenau then yes, I think it's on-demand.

Comment: I'm struggling to figure out how this works without an expansion tank.   Seems like when you open a domestic hot water tap, the pressure and temp drop and that triggers the boiler.  That, in turn, could cause the water in the heating circuit to heat up a lot (possibly even boil), especially if none of the thermostats are open. That in turn would cause a banging.

Comment: @gbronner the boiler has an internal expansion tank, the installer who removed the external one insisted that it wouldn't be necessary anymore and that probably it was previosly installed to compensate a malfunctioning of the internal expansion tank. The graph I posted should help determine whether one needs an additional tank (area B) or not (A). I am not sure e.g. of which curve to consider, so it might be that under certain conditions my plant falls into area B. Reinstalling the tank would be a simple fix (and I would also complain to the one who removed it). I'm going to have that checked.

Comment: I've never seen a boiler with an external expansion tank, but it doesn't mean that they don't exist.  All expansion tanks go can go bad, however, so if it is bad, it would act as if it wasn't there.

Comment: Have you tried lowering all the TRV temps so none of the radiators flow, then adding them back in one at a time to see 1) if problem occurs without any TRV's 2) if there is a potential for multiple TRV's open at roughly the same time increasing the pressure drop in the system. If the hammering stops, then add them back in by zone (or individually) to see where the hammering begins. This won't isolate the problem, but might point at the internal expansion unit, or air in the system, or impact of multiple TRV's activating at the same time, or another coincidental source of pressure change.

Comment: @RGHughes I did not perform these more advanced tests. Thanks for the help, at this point I'm just insisting that technicians intervene and I'll let them figure out the problem (also thanks to the help in this comments I have reached the conclusion that there is some anomaly).